# Get a single word from batch Windows output into variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running the command

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8080
```

which gives me the output

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         4576
```

Then I want to kill the task, but the PID obviously always changes, so I need to read the fifth word (in this case 4576) into a variable. How do I do this? Through googling I only managed to get the whole line

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr 8080') do set pid=%%a
echo %pid%
```

the command in single-quotes is executed, and each line of output is parsed, selecting the fifth token using the defaults.

Note the caret escaping the pipe. This is required to tell `cmd` that it's part of the command to be executed, not a redirection from a malformed statement